# How can i handle exception when i use asynctask in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Explanation:

> I am using a web service for my application.In which, every request is >using GET method. so create a class in which I also create  method to set >the url and get the response from the server.

Here, is my class which get the response from server.

```
package adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class CallAPI {
    private Context context;
    public String GetResponseGetMethod(String url) {
        URL obj;
        String Response="";
        String getMethodResponse = "";
        try {
            obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("GET Response Code :: " , ""+responseCode);
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine+"\n");
                }
                in.close();

                // print result
                getMethodResponse=response.toString();
                Log.e("Response",response.toString());
            } else {
                Log.e("GET request not worked","");
            }
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "YEs got it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "YEs Inside IO it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return getMethodResponse;
    }
}
```

Above class get response.

Here is my class where I used **Asynktask**

```
public class TabJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String jsonStr = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Utils.Pdialog(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        jsonStr = new CallAPI().GetResponseGetMethod(url);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Sometimes it takes to time to get response.

MyQuestion is:

> How can I handle this situation when it takes too time to get response.It >also raised an exception like unknowhostapi.

How can I overcome from this problem.Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: can also post the code of how are you using this method? as in `asynctask`?

Comment: You need to use asynctask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I edited my post see

Comment: It depends on your network connection, I think. Log all the results you are getting from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Milan in your callAPI class assign some value to getMehodResponse in catch blocks as follows-

```
public class CallAPI {
private Context context;
public String GetResponseGetMethod(String url) {
    URL obj;
    String Response="";
    String getMethodResponse = "";
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        Log.e("GET Response Code :: " , ""+responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine+"\n");
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            getMethodResponse=response.toString();
            Log.e("Response",response.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("GET request not worked","");
        }
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        getMethodResponse="Malformed";
        Toast.makeText(context, "YEs got it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
         getMethodResponse="IO";
        Toast.makeText(context, "YEs Inside IO it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return getMethodResponse;
}
 }
```

In TabJson class return following in doInBackground method-

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        jsonStr = new CallAPI().GetResponseGetMethod(url);


        return jsonStr;
    }
```

In TabJson class use following code in onPostExecute method-

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if (s != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              //Show pop up or alert  msg here.
            }
          }
        switch(s){
                  case "IO":
                   //Do what you want to show your user.
                     break;
                  case "Malformed":
                     //Do what you want to show your user.
                     break;
                 }
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Milan I'm not seeing any AsyncTask in your code. If you want to implement AsyncTask task follow these steps-

1.extend AsyncTask

2.override doInBackground() and postExecute method.

3. do your work in doInBackground and get response from server.
4. in postExecute handle your exeption according to your response status.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your function that deals with the server return some object that can contain all possible results, not just the success case.  So for example:

```
class Results {
    public String result;
    public Err error;
    public enum Err {
        OK, ERR1, ERR2, ERR3
    }
}
```

So if everything is OK, you set the result string to the response and the error enum to OK.  Or if there is some other error, use another enum of your definition.  In you code that receives the result, you can check the error type to determine what to do with it.

Comment: i can't understood

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            jsonStr = new CallAPI().GetResponseGetMethod(url);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

You are returning `null`. Returning string instead.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            jsonStr = new CallAPI().GetResponseGetMethod(url);

            return jsonStr;
        }
```

Now, in post execute, format it in jsonObject like this:

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            if (s != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
```

Now, you have `JSONobject` obj. Do something with it.

Comment: What is it return? Is it return response?

Comment: After your edit, my answer doesn't make any sense. You are already using asynctask in your code.

Comment: Can i set my asynctask is execute only for 10 second after 10 second it's stop their execution?   Is it possible?

Comment: Now tell me what will i do according to this situation?

Comment: I was created a method because of every time i was not put the same code in every activity and fragments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107388/discussion-between-milan-gajera-and-learner).

Answer (score -1):

use  [Async Task](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.VvYe9-J97IU) and also add permission of internet in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```